# Is it possible to initialize constexpr std::array member in a programtic way

Tags: c++, constexpr, stdarray

Lets assume I want to write struct that has a member constexpr std::array that contains first N fibs, where N is a template argument.

Something like this but with vals being avaliable at compile time:

```
template <int N>
struct first_n_fibs {
    static_assert(N>0);
    static const std::array<int, N> vals;
    static std::array<int, N> init_fibs(){
        std::array<int,N> result;
        if (N==1) {
            return std::array<int,N>{1};
        } else {
            result[0]=1;
            result[1]=1;
            for(int i =2; i<N;++i) {
                result[i]=result[i-2]+result[i-1];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
};

template<int N>
const std::array<int, N> first_n_fibs<N>::vals=init_fibs();


int main(){
    std::cout << first_n_fibs<2>::vals.back() << std::endl;
    std::cout << first_n_fibs<5>::vals.back() << std::endl;
    std::cout << first_n_fibs<6>::vals.back() << std::endl;
}
```

I suspect there is no workaround since std::array constructors are not constexpr, so if somebody knows any workarounds involving C arrays or boost I would be happy with that.

Comment: I'd like to know why you want it to be `std::array`. Besides, `first_n_fibs<n>` create a lot of instance while all these are (prefix) equal.

Comment: because IDK how to operate on C array at compile time. As for instances and duplication: I know about that, but in some cases it is worth the cost.

Comment: if you work on C array than any prefix-equal const `first_n_fibs` can be represent by single pointer to the longest array. can you provide your use case?

Comment: otherwise if you want to get only the `nth-fib` at compile time a `std::array` may be overkill.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need anything special, `constexpr` function requirements are very relaxed these days:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <int N> constexpr std::array<int, N> first_n_fibs()
{
    std::array<int, N> ret{};
    ret[0] = 0;
    if (N == 1) return ret;
    ret[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < N; i++)
        ret[i] = ret[i-2] + ret[i-1];
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto a = first_n_fibs<3>();
}
```

[(try it live)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4429cac6e67661a9)

---

> `std::array` constructors are not constexpr

Apparently it has [no user-defined constructors at all](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), so nothing stops its construction from being `constexpr`.

Comment: nice workaround, but in general I prefer to have it inside class, since having a bunch of "getter" functions is not nice(and may be slower) from design point of view.

Comment: Actually you are right, gcc was giving me lame error, all I did was that I did not initializer ret with {} like you did.

Answer (score 2):

You can use immediately called lambda:

```
struct foo {
    static constexpr auto arr = []{
        std::array<int, 6> a{};

        for (auto& e : a) {
            // stuff
        }

        return a;
    }();
};
```

But as HolyBlackCat said, `std::array` is constexpr constructible, since it has no defined constructor, only compiler defined ones.

Here's [live example at coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01d1756f84606f74)

Comment: "std::array is totally constexpr constructible" IDK the language terms, but when I put constexpr in front of member it does not compile :)

Comment: "error: constexpr static data member 'vals' must have an initializer"

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl when making a variable constexpr, you must give it a value, as your compiler is telling you. It needs an initializer. Alternatively, you can put your definition inline and mark the definition add constexpr.

Comment: Plese see my other comments, bug was me not writing {} when initializing array in my function, and GCC giving me silly error.

Comment: I still upvoted your answer, I am sorry you wasted time on helping me, but really error smelled like constexpr problem(it contained "is not usable as a constexpr function because")