# Initializing static constexpr member of type std::array in C++14

Tags: c++, arrays, static, initialization, constexpr

I'm failing to programmatically initialize a static constexpr `std::array` member.
This is a minimal example of my issue (for simplification size is known and small, thus initialization could be manual but I'd like to make the actual size a template non-type parameter, thus ruling out a manual initialization):

```cpp
#include <array>

constexpr std::size_t N = 3;
using Mat = std::array<double, N * N>;

// OK, can initialize a free constexpr Mat
constexpr Mat InitEye() noexcept {
    Mat TmpEye{0};
    for (std::size_t r = 0; r < N; ++r) {
        for (std::size_t c = 0; c < N; ++c) {
            TmpEye[r * N + c] = (r == c) ? 1. : 0.;
        }
    }
    return TmpEye;
}

// KO
class Wrapper {
   private:
    // KO cannot use it to initialize static constexpr member
    static constexpr Mat WrappedInitEye() noexcept {
        Mat TmpEye{0};
        for (std::size_t r = 0; r < N; ++r) {
            for (std::size_t c = 0; c < N; ++c) {
                TmpEye[r * N + c] = (r == c) ? 1. : 0.;
            }
        }
        return TmpEye;
    }

   public:
    static constexpr Mat Eye = WrappedInitEye();
};

// also KO
class Wrapper2 {
   public:
    // OK in C++17, still KO in C++17 due to lack of constexpr access operator
    static constexpr Mat Eye = [] {
        Mat TmpEye{0};
        for (std::size_t r = 0; r < N; ++r) {
            for (std::size_t c = 0; c < N; ++c) {
                TmpEye[r * N + c] = (r == c) ? 1. : 0.;
            }
        }
        return TmpEye;
    }();
};

int main() {
    constexpr Mat Eye = InitEye();
    constexpr Mat Eye2 = Wrapper::Eye;
    return 0;
}
```

The closest answer I found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50263306/is-it-possible-to-initialize-constexpr-stdarray-member-in-a-programtic-way) (thus the lambda version above).

Yet [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/nnoTE1vTY) si showing two issues:

1. Non lambda version never works:

```
\<source\>:32:46: error: 'static constexpr Mat Wrapper::WrappedInitEye()' called in a constant expression before its definition is complete
   32 |     static constexpr Mat Eye = WrappedInitEye();
```

2. Lambda version does not work either in C++14, due to the lack of `constexpr` access function for `std::array`

The non-lambda version gives this *"uncomplete definition"* error because:

- [constexpr initializing static member using static function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522399/constexpr-initializing-static-member-using-static-function)
- [`static constexpr` function called in a constant expression is...an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551223/static-constexpr-function-called-in-a-constant-expression-is-an-error)

But still, how can I implement a programmatic `std::array` initialization with C++14?

Comment: [`static constexpr` function called in a constant expression is...an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551223/static-constexpr-function-called-in-a-constant-expression-is-an-error)

Comment: I saw it and first thought it was unrelated but the answer actually explain point 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Why does the non-lambda version gives this "uncomplete definition" error?

Because the definition of the static member function `WrappedInitEye` is not complete until the end of the class definition. I'm not quite sure where in the standard this is addressed, but that particular error disappears if you make `WrappedInitEye` a free function instead.

> 2. How can I implement a programmatic `std::array` initialization with C++14?

Best I could do in C++14 is this:

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>

constexpr std::size_t N = 3;
using Mat = std::array<double, N * N>;

template<std::size_t Index>
static constexpr bool condition = Index / N == Index % N;

template<std::size_t Index>
constexpr auto genElement(char(*)[condition<Index>] = 0) -> double {
    return 1.;
}

template<std::size_t Index>
constexpr auto genElement(char(*)[!condition<Index>] = 0) -> double {
    return 0.;
}

template<std::size_t... Indices>
constexpr auto gen(std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    return Mat{ genElement<Indices>()... };
}

int main() {
    constexpr Mat a = gen(std::make_index_sequence<N*N>());
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nnaTK75vT)

It only works for your particular pattern (identity matrix, so a 1 when `Index / N == Index % N`, a 0 otherwise), but you might be able to modify it for more complex patterns. The `char(*)[condition<Index>()] = 0` part uses SFINAE. I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/989518/3854570).

You can also use tag dispatching:

```
template<std::size_t Index>
using Condition = std::integral_constant<bool, Index / N == Index % N>;

template<std::size_t Index>
constexpr auto genElement(std::true_type) -> double {
    return 1.;
}

template<std::size_t Index>
constexpr auto genElement(std::false_type) -> double {
    return 0.;
}

template<std::size_t... Indices>
constexpr auto gen(std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    return Mat{ genElement<Indices>(Condition<Indices>{})... };
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/64vMM818c)

Comment: I think that your idea of using a ```index_sequence``` with some partial specialization or SFINAE can be applied to more general situation. Thank you.

Comment: @Oersted I just noticed `condition` could just be a variable. Also I added a tag dispatching version, in case that's clearer.